# ¿por qué spring boot no me permite agregar archivos html?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

hola estaba creando un proyecto de spring desde una pc nueva , pero no me salen los archivos html
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

intenté añadir un proyecto con archivos html pero tampoco me los reconoce

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cual podría ser el problema ?

Comment: Parece más un problema de eclipse o de Sprint STS que de Spring boot como framework

Answer (score 1):

Da click abajo de tu texto html en el cuadro de diálogo y se van a aparecer. a mi me pasa cuando hago debug, en Mac con big Sur hay muchos problemas con la interface.

buscando maven (No refresca bien la lista)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dando click en la carpeta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muevo con las flechas arriba abajo para ver todos los resultados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que encontre https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1105974/ es que hay que usar java11 openjdk lo voy a intentar.

Comment: uff , al final pude solucionar el error y tenia que descargar el thymeleaf desde el eclipse marketplace ( help-->eclipse marketplace -->thymeleaf), es raro tener que descargarlo igual a pesar de haber creado el proyecto con esa dependencia.